# Inverse Problem for the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to learn how to solve numerically the inverse problem of the heat equation ,at the beginning i want to start with the stationary eqaution :

$-div(K\nabla u)= f $       on $ \Omega $

$u=0 $ on $\partial\Omega $

I want to go through the computation method of the adjoint  equation by the Lagrangian

do you know a book that gives enough details on this ?
or even on another equation but with enough details in the algorithm

thank you in advance

Comment: Isn't the equation ill-posed, thus making a numerical solution all but impractical?

Comment: yes you are right but there is some cases when we can prouve the problem is well posed